# Deactivate a button until all javascript conditions have been checked

Tags: javascript

I´m trying to do different javascript validations before sending a form, the problem is that I haven´t been able to prevent the form from submit, it checks the conditions and sends alerts when a conditions hasn´t been satisfied but it sends the form anyways. I want the button to either be disabled until everything is right or send a message telling user, to check the cuenta.
Thanks in advance. This is my code:

```
    <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Datos/agregar" method="post">

    Enter CLABE account:
    <input name="clabe" id="clabe" type = "text" pattern=".{17,17}" maxlength="17" required title="17 números exactamente"/>
    <input type="text" name="control" id="control" maxlength="1" size="2" required >
     Again:
     <input name="clabe2" id="clabe2" type = "text" pattern=".{17,17}" maxlength="17" required title="17 números exactamente"/>
    <input type="text" name="control2" id="control2" maxlength="1" size="2" required>
    <hr>
    Bank: <input type="text" name="Banco" id="Banco" readonly required onmousemove="comparaclabe();" >
    <hr>
    Observations: <input type="text" name="Observaciones" id="Observaciones" required>
    <hr>
    <input type="submit" id="myBtn" value="Guardar Cambios" onclick ="return compareclabe();" ><span id="msg"></span>
     <hr>
     <input type="hidden" id="cve_banco" name="cve_banco">
   </form>
    <hr>
    <script>
           function compareclabe(){
           document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
           var x1 = document.getElementById("clabe").value;
           var x2 = document.getElementById("control").value;
            var x3 = x1 + x2;
            var z1 = document.getElementById("clabe2").value;
            var z2 = document.getElementById("control2").value;
             var z3 = z1 + z2;
             if( x3 != z3){
                alert("keys are not equal");
                return false;
                }else if (x3 == z3){
                     this.someFunc(); //I want to call function someFunc and then 
          if the result is true, execute the next code
                if (true){ 
                      var cBanco = String(x3).charAt(0) + String(x3).charAt(1) + String(x3).charAt(2);
              var x = cBanco;
            switch (x) {
            case "012":
               text = "BBVA BANCOMER"; 
                break;
            case "014":
                text = "SANTANDER";
                break;
            case "032":
                text = "IXE";
                break;
            default:
            text = "No value found";
            }
            document.getElementById("Banco").value = text;   
                document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = false;
                return true; 
            }

        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
function someFunc() {
    //myFunction2();
    var x =  document.getElementById("clabe2").value;
    f2(x,'37137137137137137');
    //return true;

            }

function f2(a, b) {
    var cad = Array.from(a, (v, i) => v * b[i] % 10).join('');
  //se suman todos los digitos del array
   var value = cad,
    sum = value
        .toString()
        .split('')
        .map(Number)
        .reduce(function (a, b) {
            return a + b;
        }, 0);
//separate last digit from result
var number = sum;

// convert number to a string, then extract the first digit
var one = String(number).charAt(1);

// convert the first digit back to an integer
var one_as_number = Number(one); 
var digito_control = (10 - one_as_number); 

if (digito_control === 10 ) {
    digito_control = 0;
    var dg = digito_control;
}else{
     dg = digito_control;
}
    var z = document.getElementById("control2").value;
    if (dg != z){
        alert("checkig digit is not equal");
        return false;
    }
    else if (dg == z){
        alert("checkig digit is equal");
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can use `onsubmit` event in your form like so: `<form action='#' method='POST' onsubmit='compareclabe()'></form>` and then you can use `return` inside your code to prevent submitting if the actions were not satisfied.

Comment: I did it but it seems th, the problem is on those returns, because the form is always send regardless the result is false, and i can´t find the problem in my code

Answer (score 0):

I changed form submit button type to "button" and if all the validations are passed, then submit form from javascript. 
 See below code

```js
function compareclabe() {
  document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
  var x1 = document.getElementById("clabe").value;
  var x2 = document.getElementById("control").value;
  var x3 = x1 + x2;
  var z1 = document.getElementById("clabe2").value;
  var z2 = document.getElementById("control2").value;
  var z3 = z1 + z2;
  if (x3 != z3) {
    alert("keys are not equal");
    return false;
  } else if (x3 == z3) {
    this.someFunc(); //I want to call function someFunc and then          if the result is true, execute the next code
    if (true) {
      var cBanco = String(x3).charAt(0) + String(x3).charAt(1) + String(x3).charAt(2);
      var x = cBanco;
      switch (x) {
        case "012":
          text = "BBVA BANCOMER";
          break;
        case "014":
          text = "SANTANDER";
          break;
        case "032":
          text = "IXE";
          break;
        default:
          text = "No value found";
      }
      document.getElementById("Banco").value = text;
      document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = false;
     

  $('#form').submit(); //submit form if all validation succeeds
     
    }

  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function someFunc() {
  //myFunction2();
  var x = document.getElementById("clabe2").value;
  f2(x, '37137137137137137');
  //return true;

}

function f2(a, b) {
  var cad = Array.from(a, (v, i) => v * b[i] % 10).join('');
  //se suman todos los digitos del array
  var value = cad,
    sum = value
    .toString()
    .split('')
    .map(Number)
    .reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    }, 0);
  //separate last digit from result
  var number = sum;

  // convert number to a string, then extract the first digit
  var one = String(number).charAt(1);

  // convert the first digit back to an integer
  var one_as_number = Number(one);
  var digito_control = (10 - one_as_number);

  if (digito_control === 10) {
    digito_control = 0;
    var dg = digito_control;
  } else {
    dg = digito_control;
  }
  var z = document.getElementById("control2").value;
  if (dg != z) {
    alert("checkig digit is not equal");
    return false;
  } else if (dg == z) {
    alert("checkig digit is equal");
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Datos/agregar" method="post" id="form"> <!-- I included an id to form -->

  Enter CLABE account:
  <input name="clabe" id="clabe" type="text" pattern=".{17,17}" maxlength="17" required title="17 números exactamente" />
  <input type="text" name="control" id="control" maxlength="1" size="2" required> Again:
  <input name="clabe2" id="clabe2" type="text" pattern=".{17,17}" maxlength="17" required title="17 números exactamente" />
  <input type="text" name="control2" id="control2" maxlength="1" size="2" required>
  <hr> Bank: <input type="text" name="Banco" id="Banco" readonly required onmousemove="comparaclabe();">
  <hr> Observations: <input type="text" name="Observaciones" id="Observaciones" required>
  <hr>
  <input type="button" id="myBtn" value="Guardar Cambios" onclick="return compareclabe();"><span id="msg"></span>
  <hr>
  <input type="hidden" id="cve_banco" name="cve_banco">
</form>
<hr>
```

But there are many validation plugins where you can easily implement. No need to code from begining. Refer this for an example -> https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: It worked but now when eveything is correct and click on the button "myBtn" it doesn´t send the form, do you know what I should change?

Comment: I changed that part by "document.getElementById("form").submit();" it submits the form but it does it regardless it doesn´t check all the verifications so basically the problem continues

Comment: you have to put form submit at the very end of the validation logic. That means you must submit the form only if all the validations succeeds. So check that form submit is at the right place.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the button by default, and add event listeners to all the inputs in your form.  But be weary of other ways to submit the form, like the enter key.  I would add an onsubmit function just to prevent all ways the event can happen when you don't want it to.

```
const form = document.querySelector('form')
const inputs = [...form.querySelectorAll('input')] // convert node list to array

const isValid = () => {
  let valid = false
  disableButton()
  // handle your conditions here
  if (valid) enableButton()
  return valid;
}

inputs.forEach( input => input.addEventListener('input', isValid))
form.onsubmit = event => if (!isValid()) event.preventDefault()
```

Or ES5 if you prefer:

```
var form = document.querySelector('form');
var inputNodes = form.querySelectorAll('input');
var inputs = Array.prototype.call.slice(inputNodes); // convert node list to array

var isValid = function() {
  var valid = false;
  disableButton();
  // handle your conditions here
  if (valid) enableButton();
  return valid
}

inputs.forEach( function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('input', isValid);
});
form.onsubmit = function(event) {
  if (!isValid()) event.preventDefault();
};
```

It's also worth noting that HTML5 has a lot of [built-in validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation) you can take advantage of.